# Error when calling ValidateWorkflowMarkupAndCreateSupportObjects

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I created a workflow in sharepoint designer then i exported xoml, xoml.rules, xoml.wfconfig.xml files from it.

I want to deploy these files in sharepoint using a host application (Windows Forms application). So, I call `ValidateWorkflowMarkupAndCreateSupportObjects` and `AssociateWorkflowMarkup` method from the `WebPartPagesWebService` class.
Here's the code:

```
string XomlFile = @"D:\wkf\rami workflow designer.xoml";
string RulesFile = @"D:\wkf\rami workflow designer.xoml.rules";
string ConfigFile = @"D:\wkf\rami workflow designer.xoml.wfconfig.xml";
string flag = "2";

websvcWebPartPages.WebPartPagesWebService service = new websvcWebPartPages.WebPartPagesWebService();
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.PreAuthenticate = true;
string result = service.ValidateWorkflowMarkupAndCreateSupportObjects(XomlFile, RulesFile, ConfigFile, flag);
service.AssociateWorkflowMarkup(ConfigFile, "V1.0");
```

`ValidateWorkflowMarkupAndCreateSupportObjects` return "`Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1`".

And `AssociateWorkflowMarkup` throws `Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException`.

The Logs file:

```
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002    3dccdc9b-af66-4f72-b41f-51a4d1774b35

SOAP exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception of HRESULT : 0x80070002)   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs)  
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException, ...    3dccdc9b-af66-4f72-b41f-51a4d1774b35 ...SPBasePermissions& permMask)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowNoCodeSupport.LoadWorkflowBytesElevated(SPFile file, Int32 fileVer, Int32& userid, DateTime& lastModified)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowNoCodeSupport.LoadWorkflowBytes(SPFile file, Int32 fileVer, Int32& userid)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.WebPartPagesWebService.AssociateWorkflowMarkup(String configUrl, String configVersion)    3dccdc9b-af66-4f72-b41f-51a4d1774b35.
```

Comment: Pleae don't repeat tags in question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass in *file names*, but the method requires the *actual XML*. (Ask yourself: you are calling a web service, so typically remotely, then how could the server read any files from your local PC's drive?) Read the MSDN documentation; however, note that the [2013 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.soapserver.webpartpageswebservice.validateworkflowmarkupandcreatesupportobjects.aspx) is not very clear about it and you have to look at the [2007 version of the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774840%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. `ValidateWorkflowMarkupAndCreateSupportObjects` return now `"<Success><TaskList ID=\"{B58DE92C-7F70-4F9E-BD32-9DAE3B9F0056}\" /></Success>"`. But the same exception is thrown. I modified the last line in code by `service.AssociateWorkflowMarkup("Workflows/rami workflow designer/rami workflow designer.xoml.wfconfig.xml", "V1.0");` but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @RamiNeji I am doing similar things and stuck same way you as were while publishing *.wfconfig.xml. If you have solved this, please post solution.